Connect Azure Log Workspace with Data Collection Rule (Terrraform) custom json logs
I'm working on migrating from Azure Log Analytics Agent to Azure Monitoring Agent. It's for the custom JSON logs. I have performed the steps from the portal and is working fine now, but I have to do the same via the terraform code.
For creating the table for the same, I have used the following code
  name      = "DCR_Table_TC_Example_CL"
  parent_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.la.id
  type      = "Microsoft.Insights/dataCollectionRules@2022-06-01"
  body = jsonencode(
    {
      "properties" : {
        "schema" : {
          "name" : "DCR_Table_TC_Example_CL",
          "columns" : [
            {
              "name" : "TimeGenerated",
              "type" : "datetime",
              "description" : "The time at which the data was generated"
            },
            {
              "name" : "RawData",
              "type" : "string",
              "description" : "Log level"
            },
            {
              "name" : "FilePath",
              "type" : "string",
              "description" : "file path"
            }
          ]
        },
        "retentionInDays" : 90,
        "totalRetentionInDays" : 90
      }
    }
  )
}

Now, I'm trying to create DCR by using the following code -
  name                        = "example-dcr-terraform"
  resource_group_name         = module.example.rg.name
  location                    = module.example.rg.location
  data_collection_endpoint_id = azurerm_monitor_data_collection_endpoint.example-dce-terraform.id

  destinations {
    log_analytics {
      name                  = "example-destination-log"
      workspace_resource_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.la.id
    }
  }

  data_sources {
    log_file {
      name          = "example-logfile"
      format        = "text"
      streams       = ["Custom-Json-${azapi_resource.data_collection_logs_table.name}"]
      file_patterns = ["/var/log/vault_audit.log"]
    }
  }

  data_flow {
    streams       = ["Custom-Json-${azapi_resource.data_collection_logs_table.name}"]
    destinations  = log_analytics_id
    output_stream = "Custom-${azapi_resource.data_collection_logs_table.name}"
  }
}

My table and data collection endpoint are created. My log file contains data in json format, but how do I pass the path and format of this json log file to DCR?
I have tried finding an example on internet as well as on stack overflow, but I couldn't find any solution for this. If anybody could guide me for the same.
Thanks!

Are you sure that you are passing correct format here. format  = "text" in the data source block. @thelearner

Hello @Jahnavi, that's where my question is, mine is json log file. How do I pass it as the format field only takes the text format. I'm new to Azure and DCR both. So, just trying to understand.

Have you tried using azapi provider. @thelearner

Yes @Jahnavi, I have created table using azapi provider

You need to convert the file from json to text format as explained in the below answer clearly. @thelearner


My log file contains data in Json format, but how do I pass the path and format of this Json log file to DCR:

As I mentioned in the comments, only format = "text"supports in the data_source block when creating DCR. In order to pass the Json logs, you need to convert the Json file logs into text format. For conversion, use the online available convertors   or plugin tools.
My sample converted file:

Alternatively, to avoid any issues with the converters use below python code for direct conversion.
Conversion using Python
import pandas as pds

df = pd.read_json(r"C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\Jahnavi\My posts\Python\new 26.json")
df.to_csv(r"C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Jahnavi\My posts\Python\newtext.txt", index=False)


Your code will be the same but just you need to change the path of the newly generated text file after conversion.
I tried the same in my environment by following the above and was successful as shown below.
log_file {
      name          = "example-logfile"
      format        = "text"
      streams       = ["Custom-Json-${azapi_resource.data_collection_logs_table.name}"]
      file_patterns = xxxx
      settings {
        text {
          record_start_timestamp_format = "ISO 8601"
        }
      }
    }



Reference:
logstash tool plugin.

Have you tried it in your environment? @thelearner

Hello @Jahnavi I got busy with other priority tasks. I will check it this week and update.

Sure. Kindly check and update. @thelearner
